# How can I do RTSP Streaming on my android application using url?

Tags: android, streaming, webcam, live, rtsp

I want to send username and password **(for verification)** to do live RTSP streaming in my android application using RTSP Url.

I am using this [link](https://github.com/spex66/RTSP-Camera-for-Android), but it is not working and it has no option for send username and password.

Answer (score 1):

First you should contact authors of the code for that kind of support.

You may also consider using commercial SDKs to enable RTSP streaming for your apps, [like this one](https://wmspanel.com/mobile_library) or [this one](http://www.realtimelibs.com/#feature_2).